# Download Dynamically Generated File in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to implement a file download in ASP.NET MVC. Searching the Web, I found code like this:

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
    return File(filename, "text/csv", Server.UrlEncode(filename));
}
```

That's nice, but I want to create the contents of this file dynamically.

I realize I could dynamically create the file, and then use the syntax above to download that file. But wouldn't it be more efficient if I could simply write my contents directly to the response? Is this possible in MVC?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an overly simplified version of the code I ended up using. It meets my needs.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.csv");
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

    // Write all my data
    Response.Write(...);
    Response.End();

    // Not sure what else to do here
    return Content(String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's correct or not but I usually return null.  I'm interested in knowing if there is a better way.

Comment: Yeah, I tried returning a non-empty string but I couldn't see that it went anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the headers. Instead of Response.Write() I actually return a regular .cshtml View that just happens to return non-html text content that I want (an .ini file) and still takes advantage of a Razor template with @{Layout=null}.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution is to use the overload for File() that accepts a stream.

In my case, it's a csv that I need to generate from a Controller Action, so it's a bit like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadInvalidData(int fileId)
{
    string invalidDataCsv = this.importService.GetInvalidData(fileId);
    string downloadFileName = "error.csv";

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    writer.Write(invalidDataCsv);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    return File(stream, "text/csv", downloadFileName);
}
```

Note you should **not** dispose of the Stream or the StreamWriter before passing it to the File() function because disposing of either will close the stream making it unusable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that's what a FileStreamResult does.  But if you don't want to use it, just write it to the response.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: When you say 'create the file', are you able to create the stream?  Is that the help you're looking for?

Comment: For simplicity, let's just say I have a string. I want to write that string to the response as a text file. I consider it to be more efficient if I am not required to first write that string to a file.

Comment: Perhaps Response.WriteFile() or Response.Write()?  you'd still have to set Response.ContentType based on the type.

Comment: Yes, possibly `Response.Write()` (since I don't want to have an actual file). I'm looking into this.

Comment: It looks like 'return Content()' might do what you want.

Comment: Well, my real data is much more than a single string. So `Response.Write()` seems the most likely candidate. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download it as a file then you can try a custom `ActionResult` as @Tungano suggest, else if you want to directly into the response then the built-in `ContentResult` will do but it'll work with simple strings and in the complex scenario you have to extend it.

```
public class CustomFileResult : FileContentResult
{
  public string Content { get; private set; }

  public string DownloadFileName { get; private set; }

  public CustomFileResult(string content, string contentType, string downloadFileName)
    : base(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content), contentType)
  {
    Content = content;
    DownloadFileName = downloadFileName;
  }

  public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  {
    context.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DownloadFileName);

    base.ExecuteResult(context);
  }
}


public class BlogController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  public CustomFileResult GetMyFile()
  {
    return CustomFile("Hello", "text/plain", "myfile.txt");
  }

  protected internal CustomFileResult CustomFile(string content, string contentType, string downloadFileName)
  {
    return new CustomFileResult(content, contentType, downloadFileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite follow exactly what you are doing there, but it still seems like you're referencing a file on disk, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly write to the Response.OutputStream similar to how you would stream to a file. To keep it testable and MVC'ish, you can create your own ActionResult class which does the streaming of a model object you pass it.